# Netlogo get nobody when trying to set players

Tags: netlogo

I want to set the ball-owner, but It doesn't work and I have a nobody instead.
Here my code:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-players-red
  setup-players-blue
  setup-ball 
  print BALL-OWNER
end


to setup-ball
  create-balls 1 [
    setxy 5 -1
    set shape "ball basketball"
    set size 2.5
    set the-ball self
    set BALL-OWNER one-of players with [distance the-ball = 0]
    set owner BALL-OWNER
  ]
end

to setup-players-red
  create-players 1[
    set color red
    set shape "person"
    set size 5
    setxy (5)
    setxy (-1)
    set team "red"
  ]

end

to setup-players-blue 
create-players 1[
    set color blue
    set shape "person"
    set size 5
    setxy (-5)
    setxy (1)
    set team "blue" 
  ]
end
```

So why I have an "nodoby" print instead players 1/2? 
What am I doing wrong?
I also try to put the

> " set BALL-OWNER one-of players with [distance the-ball = 0]"

in the setup statement but I have the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, try to submit code as a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that users can just copy and paste your code into a blank NetLogo instance and run your model.

Your `setxy` code for the players is problematic- if that is fixed, I don't get the same error you describe- the code below runs for me:

```
globals [ ball-owner the-ball owner ]

breed [ players player ]
breed [ balls ball ]

players-own [ team ]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-players-red
  setup-players-blue
  setup-ball 
  print BALL-OWNER
end


to setup-ball
  create-balls 1 [
    setxy 5 -1
    set shape "circle"
    set size 2.5
    set the-ball self
    set BALL-OWNER one-of players with [distance the-ball = 0]
    set owner BALL-OWNER
  ]
end

to setup-players-red
  create-players 1[
    set color red
    set shape "person"
    set size 5
    setxy 5 -1
    set team "red"
  ]

end

to setup-players-blue 
create-players 1[
    set color blue
    set shape "person"
    set size 5
    setxy -5 1
    set team "blue" 
  ]
end
```

Comment: thank you, It works, as you said the problem was the incorrect setxy, In my code I have used  setxy (5) (-1) but It is incorrect.